# in line SVG in CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have lots of inline SVG's within my CSS doc which were working fine, now I can't get them to work at all. I think it might be something to do with installing a SSL? Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
.facebook{
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='50' height='50' viewBox='0 0 50 50'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='a' d='M7.759 7.759h34.483v34.483H7.759z'/%3E%3Cmask id='b' width='34.483' height='34.483' x='0' y='0' fill='%23fff'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23a'/%3E%3C/mask%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cuse stroke='%23EE5885' stroke-width='2' mask='url%28%23b%29' transform='rotate%2845 25 25%29' xlink:href='%23a'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23EE5885' d='M26.422 33.581v-9.277h2.55l.338-3.197h-2.888l.004-1.6c0-.834.08-1.281 1.272-1.281h1.594v-3.197h-2.55c-3.064 0-4.143 1.55-4.143 4.159v1.92h-1.91v3.196h1.91v9.277h3.823z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
```

Comment: What changed? They seem fine to me.

Comment: You can filename.svg and set background

Comment: Ex: background: url(filename.svg);

Comment: Its really odd, https://www.studentlifelettings.co.uk its the social media links down the bottom Twitter and Facebook.